# Web applications validation guideline

Tags: validation

Suppose I have a web application where:

- the user inputs a number in a textbox
- then he submits the form
- the server receives the submit and reads the number
- the server stores the number in a database table

Now, suppose that this number has a constraint: i.e. it must be non negative. How this constraint should be enforced?

- HTML validation during input: i.e. the input textbox has min: 0; however, if the user modifies the DOM he can input whatever he wants
- Javascript validation before submit: i.e. onsubmit a js script checks that input value is >= 0; however, if the user injects some code he can override this check
- Server validation after submit: i.e. when the server receive the value, it checks if it is >= 0, if so it stores on database otherwise it returns the error to the user; however, first this is not user friendly since the user knows about its mistake only after submit, and second if server code has a bug an invalid value could be still be written in the database
- Database validation during insert: i.e. the table columns has "CHECK >= 0" constraint; however, this is not user friendly as before, and also it is not straightforward to parse the db error from server to understand why the query has failed

Since every way as a drawback, I guess one should implement a combination of those. However, I find it very redundant to insert the validation in all these places to gain both data integrity and user experience. What if I have to change the constraint i.e. to > 0 instead of >= 0? I have to remember to change it in all places, in input textbox, in onsubmit method, in server request, and in table constraints. This is very redundant and leads to bugs.

What are the best practices for validation?